# How to map a List of Objects in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this List of objects

```
const List categories = [
  {'title': 'category 1', 'value': 1000},
  {'title': 'category 2', 'value': 2000},
  {'title': 'category 3', 'value': 3000},
];
```

And I'm trying to map this list to render some UI in a Column widget, so I did this

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: categories.map((e) => Category(title: e.title, value: e.value)).toList(),
),
```

But it gives me this error
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, I guess you came from `javascript`, well dart is different a little bit, the elements inside the List are called maps, with `Map` type, to get a value from that map you need to get it like this :

```
map["key"]
```

the keys should be `String`, so in your case, this will work fine :

```
`Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: categories.map((e) => Category(title: e["title"], value: 
  e["value"])).toList(),
),
```

Comment: Is it that obvious? XD, But anyways it works as it should be. Thank You

Comment: no problem mate, selecting this as the right answer could help someone else